# What would be the consequences of action-reaction pair not being anti-parallel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, thought-experiment

In the real world, action-reaction pair always make an angle of exactly at 180ᵒ. But what would happen if instead it was something like, say 179.9ᵒ. What would be the weird effects?

I started off by thinking about a block lying on a surface. There is a force ***mg*** acting on it in downward direction. So the block exerts a ***normal force*** on the surface in downward direction. But now the ***reaction normal force*** by the surface on the block would make an angle with vertical.

The thing is that the forces on the block are not balanced (there is still a net force). Its pointing somewhere downwards. Now exactly what will happen? Horizontal force make it move sideways is okay but vertical forces not being balanced will result in what?

[image: Free Body Diagram of the situation]

Also as the block start sliding, the friction also do weird things. And things happening between the individual atoms of the block are just on a whole different level.

Can anyone give me a big picture *(and some details if possible)* of what that world behave like. This thought is not letting me sleep.

Answer (score 2):

The lack of symmetry if the reaction was not in the opposite direction to the action suggests this could not be a physical law (how would you choose the plane in which the action and reaction lie ?).

However, if it were a physical law then internal forces within objects would not cancel out - we can only ignore internal forces because they form action/reaction pairs which have no net effect on the object as a whole. So all objects would move about randomly as a result of un-matched internal forces between their constituent atoms or molecules.